# asp.net web api file upload without saving

Tags: file-upload, cordova, asp.net-web-api

Ok, so I am writing a service to recieve file uploads from an iPhone application through phonegap.  They send me a file and I am trying to grab the actual file without saving it to any type of file system.  Currently this is what I have

```c#
[HttpPost]
public string processRequest()
{
    string ext = "Entered";
    Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync<MultipartMemoryStreamProvider>(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider()).ContinueWith((tsk) =>
    {
        ext = "Request";
        MultipartMemoryStreamProvider prvdr = tsk.Result;

        foreach (HttpContent ctnt in prvdr.Contents)
        {
            ext = "Foreach";
            // You would get hold of the inner memory stream here
            Stream stream = ctnt.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
            if (stream == null)
            {
                ext = "Null Stream";
            }
            Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
            if (ImageFormat.Jpeg.Equals(img.RawFormat))
            {
                ext = "jpeg";
            }
            else if (ImageFormat.Png.Equals(img.RawFormat))
            {
                ext = "Png";
            }
            else if (ImageFormat.Gif.Equals(img.RawFormat))
            {
                ext = "Gif";
            }
            // do something witht his stream now
        }
    });
    return ext;
}
```

I have put various responses in there so I can see where the function is getting to.  Right now it always returns "Entered" which means its not even reading the content of the request, the end game is for me to grab the file object, convert it into an image and then to base 64.  Any direction would be appreciated.  Remember I want to do this without any file system so no solutions that involve mapping a path to a server folder.

Ok so a little update, I have edited my code according to my first response and at least it attempts to execute now but it just gets infinitely stuck inside the code.  This happens during the ReadAsMultipartAsync function

```c#
[HttpPost]
public string processRequest()
{
    string ext = "Entered";
    Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider()).ContinueWith((tsk) =>
    {
        ext = "Request";
        MultipartMemoryStreamProvider prvdr = tsk.Result;

        foreach (HttpContent ctnt in prvdr.Contents)
        {
            ext = "Foreach";
            // You would get hold of the inner memory stream here
            Stream stream = ctnt.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
            if (stream == null)
            {
                ext = "Null Stream";
            }
            Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
            if (ImageFormat.Jpeg.Equals(img.RawFormat))
            {
                ext = "jpeg";
            }
            else if (ImageFormat.Png.Equals(img.RawFormat))
            {
                ext = "Png";
            }
            else if (ImageFormat.Gif.Equals(img.RawFormat))
            {
                ext = "Gif";
            }
            // do something witht his stream now
        }
    }).Wait();
    return ext;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block inside `ContinueWith` also runs asynchronously (if you look at the signature for ContinueWith, you'll see that it returns a `Task` as well). So, with the above code, essentially you're returning before any of that has a chance to execute.

Try doing:

```
Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync().ContinueWith(...).Wait();
```

Also, not sure you need to go to the trouble of doing `Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync<MultipartMemoryStreamProvider>(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider())`; I believe `Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync()` should suffice.

Hope that helps!